# Get date object from UTC string without changing the timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UTC date string `"Sat, 24 Jun 2017 06:26:56 GMT"`. I am unable to get a `Date` object from the string. I want the `Date` object without any change in the timezone. I have tried these things

1. `new Date("Sat, 24 Jun 2017 06:26:56 GMT")`. This gives me my machine's timezone.
2. `new Date(Date.parse("Sat, 24 Jun 2017 06:26:56 GMT"))`. Same result as above.

Is it possible to get the date without timezone change and without using `Moment.js`

Comment: Actually your Date object should already be in UTC...

Answer (score -2):

If you set your date to a variable then check for the timezone it should be yours, so the date is kept at UTC, try the following :

```
var d = new Date("Sat, 24 Jun 2017 06:26:56 GMT");
console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

It should display your timezone in minutes so in your case (considering India) -550.

If you want to redisplay as UTC date, simply use the `toUTCString()`, like this:

```
 d.toUTCString()
```

Comment: That's right. But I don't want my timezone. I want the date in UTC itself.

Comment: The `Date` as an object is a kind of data that store a Date in a particular ordered way (like a "hash") with some metadata (like the day, the year, the month etc..) and some methods.. So the value itself when you create your date is registered as an UTC date. If you want to pull back that value in UTC string as declared at the beginning, try with the `toUTCString()` method eg. `dUTC = d.toUTCString();`